# Why i cannot convert NSString to NSData

Tags: objective-c

In my People.h, I implement NSCoding,
In People.m:

```
@implementation People
@synthesize name;

- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    [aCoder encodeObject:name forKey:@"name"];
}



-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.name = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

In my viewDidLoad function of controller.

```
People *people1 = [[People alloc] init];
people1.name = @"kevin";


NSData *saveData = [NSKeyedArchiver  archivedDataWithRootObject:people1];

NSString *saveDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:saveData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSData *resultData = [saveDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

People *people2 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:resultData];
NSLog(@"%@",people2.name);


[super viewDidLoad];
```

Why i got a null at the end of this function.
Did I hava some mistakes?

Thanks!

Comment: The purpose why I do like this is that I need to keep the NSString object in my sqlite database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you were trying to unarchive Peopla out of NSString, try this

```
NSData *saveData = [NSKeyedArchiver  archivedDataWithRootObject:people1];
People *people2 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:saveData];
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I add some codes between your code because I need to save that NSData in my sqlite. When I get the NSData from a NSString, there will be a error.

Comment: What you get is binary data, if you need to transfer to and from database using string, you need to encode it and I think NSASCIIStringEncoding is not enough. did you try to save it as binary data, not string? Would be better. Or as base64 converted string.

Comment: the point is after I convert NSData to NSString, and then convert NSString to NSData, I cannot unarchiveObject people object from the new NSData. I don't know the reason. Thanks

Comment: again: NSASCIIStringEncoding cannot be true, ASCII character set contains only 127 characters and cannot be used to encode binary data except using something like base64 encoding. Try another encoding.